# Vertical-Align Top in HTML 3.1

Tags: html

I am compelled to realize an HTML table in HTML 3.1 (no, there is no chance to upgrade :( )

Now, I created a simple table with two columns.

The first column only has one row of text, the second column has more text. Now the first column gets vertically aligned in the center (standard behaviour).

How can I make the column vertically aligned to top in HTML 3.1? :/

Thanks for help!

Comment: There is no HTML 3.1, and never was. You should clarify the specific situation where the document will be displayed or otherwise processed; this would make it possible to know what HTML will really be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either attribute [`valign`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp) or css property [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

```
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="top">1</td>
<td>2<br />3<br />4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

or with css

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is safest to align both columns to the top (just in case the content some day changes so that the first cell content becomes taller). You can this by setting vertical alignment on a `tr` element; it then affects all cells in that row. You need to do that per row in HTML, however (in CSS, you could use just one rule):

```
<table>
  <tr valign=top><td>...<td>...
  <tr valign=top><td>...<td>...
  ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do this with the following CSS:

```
td, th {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Now every table cell will have the text vertically aligned to the top. Please do not use the HTML version (`valign`) for this, since CSS is the right way these days.

Just as information for further developing when you do have the chance to use HTML5: the `valign` is not supported in HTML5. It will probably work, but the markup would be invalid.

Comment: HTML5 drafts *require* continued support to attributes like `valign` (in addition to declaring them obsolete).